# I am Not Able Lode CSV file Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, upload, file-not-found, import-csv

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_83/222635537.py in <module>
      3 import numpy as np
      4 #Load the data
----> 5 df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Vrinda_Store_2022.csv')
      6 print(df)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    585 
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    587 
    588 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    480 
    481     # Create the parser.
--> 482     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    483 
    484     if chunksize or iterator:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    809             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    810 
--> 811         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    812 
    813     def close(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1038             )
   1039         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1040         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1041 
   1042     def _failover_to_python(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
     49 
     50         # open handles
---> 51         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
     52         assert self.handles is not None
     53 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
    220         Let the readers open IOHandles after they are done with their potential raises.
    221         """
--> 222         self.handles = get_handle(
    223             src,
    224             "r",

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    700         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    701             # Encoding
--> 702             handle = open(
    703                 handle,
    704                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Vrinda_Store_2022.csv'
```

the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Load the data
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Vrinda_Store_2022.csv')
print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read this. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: well, the error is clear - there is no such file `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Vrinda_Store_2022.csv`

Comment: that file name does not exist at that path. Check the path, spelling and case.

Comment: Hello, do you know how to verify the presence of a file ? [How do I check whether a file exists without exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82831/12846804). Please add the test outcome in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This means the file you're trying to load doesn't exist, or at least doesn't exist in that folder.

Try checking that the file and path are spelled correctly.
You can see the path by double-clicking the address bar in the file explorer if you want to double-check.